# How can one access methods in a child template from a parent in .NET core 8 Blazor (and vice versa)?

Tags: .net, methods, blazor, components, webapi

`

**Environment**: .Net 8 Blazor WebApp Interactive render mode is Auto (Server and WebAssembly) and Interactive locations is Per page/component.
**Situation**: I have multiple razor pages using common components (templates). I have set a number of Parameters, including select EventCallbacks.
**Questions**:

1. How can I call a method in the Templated component from the Parent razor page's code?
2. Another related question is about accessing the Parent razor's methods from the Templated component; namely, is it possible to have an EventCallback in the template to return a value? If so, how?
3. I have tried Parameters and EventCallbacks. I have used the "Callback".InvokeAsync(parameter) to call a an EventCAllback method in the parent, however, I also need to return values from this InvokeAsync call.
4. In terms of having the Parent call a method in the child (templated component) the only approach that I have discovered is to register the component's instance with the parent and then call a method that is public in the component (which may violate best practices).

I just believe that I must be missing something; an easier and better approach to directly accessing methods in the child component. If I were building this in MAUI, then Interfaces might be the answer, however, I suspect that in .NET 8 there is a better, built in structure to handle this. I am hopeful that someone might clear this up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Blazor, you can achieve communication between a parent component and a child component via different ways:

#### Calling a method in the Templated component from the Parent razor page's code:

1. **Using `@ref` attribute:**

   In the parent Razor page:

   ```html
   <TemplateComponent @ref="templateRef" />

   @code {
       private TemplateComponent templateRef;

       private void CallMethodInTemplateComponent()
       {
           templateRef.MethodInTemplate();
       }
   }
   ```

   In the Templated component:

   ```html
   @code {
       public void MethodInTemplate()
       {
           // Your logic here
       }
   }
   ```

#### Accessing the Parent razor's methods from the Templated component:

1. **Using Parameters and EventCallbacks:**

   In the parent Razor page:

   ```html
   <TemplateComponent ParentMethod="@ParentMethod" />

   @code {
       private void ParentMethod()
       {
           // Your logic here
       }
   }
   ```

   In the Templated component:

   ```html
   @code {
       [Parameter]
       public Action ParentMethod { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   You can then invoke `ParentMethod.Invoke()` in the Templated component to call the parent's method.
2. **Returning a value from an EventCallback:**

   In the Templated component:

   ```html
   <button @onclick="CallParentMethod">Call Parent Method</button>

   @code {
       [Parameter]
       public EventCallback<int> ParentMethod { get; set; }

       private async Task CallParentMethod()
       {
           var result = 42; // Your value
           await ParentMethod.InvokeAsync(result);
       }
   }
   ```

   In the parent Razor page:

   ```html
   <TemplateComponent ParentMethod="@HandleParentMethod" />

   @code {
       private void HandleParentMethod(int result)
       {
           // Use the result here
       }
   }
   ```

This approach allows you to both call methods in the Templated component from the parent and return values from the Templated component to the parent using `EventCallback` with a specified type